# SQL Insert from 2 tables with multiple rows on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update some budgeting data in an SQL database. I have 1 table which is the set of data for this year, and another table which contains last years (and I need to insert this years data into).
During the insert I need to create a unique row for each sitenumber which is in a temporary table, against each site number needs to be this years information (week number, startdate, enddate etc).
I have tried using a subquery (but obviously this fails as the subquery for the getting the site number will return multiple records. So I am trying a `cursor`, however although it doesn't error, it doesn't insert any date. if anyone has any ideas that'd be great.
This is my `cursor code`

```
create table #tempSiteNoTable (SiteNo int)
insert into #tempSiteNoTable
Select distinct(SiteNumber)
from Lynx_Period_Lookup

    begin tran xxx
    Declare @SiteNNo int

    Declare SiteNumberCursor Cursor FOR
        Select 
            SiteNo from #tempSiteNoTable where SiteNo = @SiteNNo
        Open SiteNumberCursor
    Fetch next from SiteNumberCursor
    Into @SiteNNo while @@fetch_status = 0

    begin
        insert into Lynx_Period_Lookup
          (SiteNumber,SubPeriod,StartDate,EndDate,[Year],Period,[Week],BusinessCalendarNumber,BusinessCalendarName)
          Select
            @SiteNNo,
            SubPeriod,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            2014 as year,
            Period,
            WeekNo,
            BusinessCalendarNumber,
           BusinessCalendarName
            from accountingperiods
           Fetch next from SiteNumberCursor
           into @SiteNNo

    End
        Close SiteNumberCursor
    Deallocate SiteNumberCursor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this **without a CURSOR** - and quite easily, too!

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempSiteNoTable (SiteNo int)

INSERT INTO #tempSiteNoTable(SiteNo)
   SELECT DISTINCT (SiteNumber)
   FROM dbo.Lynx_Period_Lookup

INSERT INTO dbo.Lynx_Period_Lookup(SiteNumber, SubPeriod, StartDate, EndDate, [Year], Period, [Week], BusinessCalendarNumber, BusinessCalendarName)
    SELECT
        t.SiteNo,
        ap.SubPeriod,
        ap.StartDate,
        ap.EndDate,
        2014 as year,
        ap.Period,
        ap.WeekNo,
        ap.BusinessCalendarNumber,
        ap.BusinessCalendarName
    FROM
        #tempSiteNoTable t
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.AccountingPeriods ap ON ... (how are those two sets of data related?)...
```

The only point I don't know - how are `AccountingPeriods` and `#tempSiteNoTable` related - what common column do they share?

That's all there is to it - no cursor, no messing around with **row-by-agonizing-row** (RBAR) processing - just one, nice, clean **set-based** statement and you're done

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a CROSS JOIN; try the following snippet of code.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Week int, StartDate datetime)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (sitenumber int)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Week, StartDate)
VALUES (1, '2014-01-01'), (2, '2014-01-08')

INSERT INTO @Table2 (sitenumber)
VALUES (1), (2)

SELECT *
FROM @Table1 CROSS JOIN @Table2
```